# printing an xts object

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I am trying to create an `xts` object of [this S&P500 sample](https://pastebin.com/vY6ewfZU). This is the code I am using:

```
sp500 <- read.csv2("SP500.csv",
               stringsAsFactors = F,
               header = T,
               sep = ",",
               na.strings = ".")
sp500$DATE <- as.Date(sp500$DATE)
sp500$SP500 <- as.numeric(sp500$SP500)
library(xts)
sp500idx <- xts(sp500$SP500, order.by = as.Date(sp500$DATE))
```

When I check `str(sp500idx)` this appears to have worked. Yet when I try to print the new object by simply typing `sp500idx` I get the following:

```
!> sp500idx
            m.c.seq.row..seq.n...seq.col..drop...FALSE.
 2014-03-10                                     1877.17
 2014-03-11                                     1867.63
 2014-03-12                                     1868.20
 2014-03-13                                     1846.34
 2014-03-14                                     1841.13
 2014-03-17                                     1858.83
 2014-03-18                                     1872.25
 2014-03-19                                     1860.77
 2014-03-20                                     1872.01
 2014-03-21                                     1866.52
        ...
 2014-07-15                                     1973.28
 2014-07-16                                     1981.57
 2014-07-17                                     1958.12
 2014-07-18                                     1978.22
 2014-07-21                                     1973.63
 2014-07-22                                     1983.53
 2014-07-23                                     1987.01
 2014-07-24                                     1987.98
 2014-07-25                                     1978.34
 2014-07-28                                     1978.91
```

What does the first line in this output mean, i.e.

```
m.c.seq.row..seq.n...seq.col..drop...FALSE.
```

I have a feeling that it has to do with the number of observations in the `xts` object. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can't replicate this. I just get an xts object with a single column with the values, no column names at all.

Comment: Hi @thelatemail, this indeed what I also get when there are fewer observations in the dataset than what I posted.

Comment: I can replicate this. R 4.3.3 on Windows 11. xts version ‘0.13.2’. Have you tried to contact `maintainer("xts")`?

Comment: I am using R 4.3.2 on Linux and xts version 0.13.1 which loads zoo version 1.8-12. I have accepted @GGrothendieck's answer. Yet it might indeed be an idea to contact the maintainer of the package to clarify what is going pear-shaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce that but in any case the way to do this is shown below.

To make this self contained we will generate the input file in the Note at the end.  Then read it in using `read.csv.zoo` and convert that to xts.

```
library(xts)

sp500 <- "SP500.csv" |> read.csv.zoo(drop = FALSE) |> as.xts()

sp500
##              SP500
## 2014-03-10 1877.17
## 2014-03-11 1867.63
## 2014-03-12 1868.20

class(sp500)
## [1] "xts" "zoo"

is.numeric(sp500)
## [1] TRUE

class(time(sp500))
## [1] "Date"
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "DATE,SP500
2014-03-10,1877.17
2014-03-11,1867.63
2014-03-12,1868.20
"

cat(Lines, file = "SP500.csv")
```

### Comment

Regarding your comment `|>` says insert the left hand side of the pipe into the first argument of the function call on the right hand side of the pipe and run it so the pipeline shown is the same as `as.xts(read.csv.zoo(sp500, drop = FALSE))` but flows from left to right and avoids harder to read nested parentheses .

For further info on any package go to, for example, https://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo and review the vignettes, if any, the reference manual and any other links there.

To get further info on a command look at its help page, for example, `?zoo`, `?xts`, `?read.csv.zoo`, etc.  To see examples look at the bottom of that command's help page. Issuing a command at the R console without the () will show its R source code, e.g. `read.csv.zoo` .

`read.csv.zoo` is a simple wrapper of `read.zoo` (based on `read.csv` instead of `read.table`) and there is an entire vignette on `read.zoo` .

Comment: That indeed works beautifully! Thanks for this. I cannot follow your syntax however. Would you have a pointer for me to learn about the `|>` operator please? Also, I am left puzzled when to use functions of `zoo` and of `xts`. The literature is not entirely clear on the pros and cons of these packages, at least to the novice. Is there an instructive read out there that offers a concise introduction?

Comment: See Comment section added at end.

Comment: Since the original data file I posted, see [S&P 500](https://pastebin.com/vY6ewfZU), contains missings indicated by ```.``` I read in your excellent [xts vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-read.pdf) that the import command can be modified to ```read.csv.zoo(drop = FALSE, ,  na.strings = ".")```,

Comment: Thanks also for your general suggestions. What I am still not 100% clear about is whether a beginner should go for the ```zoo``` class or for the ```xts``` class when looking at daily financial data with missings such as the S&P 500 downloadable from [FRED](https://fred.stlouisfed.org): What are examples of situations in which the former won't do? My intention is to use as few classes as possible, for didactic reasons. Thanks for any advice you might have!

Comment: Is there a difference between creating an ```xts``` object by ```as.xts()``` or by ```xts()```? I am asking since I noticed the following: Importing the data in ```xlsx``` format via ```data <- read_excel("SP500.xlsx", na = "#N/A")``` creates a tibble with a POSIXct date index which is converted fine when ```as.xts()``` is used but which prints my original error when I use ```data <- xts(x = data2$SP500, order.by = data2$date)```.

Comment: `as.xts` is a generic which dispatches specific methods such as `as.xts.data.frame`  or `as.xts.zoo` depending on the class of the first argument to `as.xts`.  `methods(as.xts)` will show the available methods that it can dispatch to and for any of them use, for example,  `getAnywhere("as.xts.data.frame")` or `getAnywhere("as.xts.zoo")`to see the source code of the method.  In general the ``as.xts`` methods  ultimately call `xts`,

Answer (score 0):

As the maintainer of `xts` points out [here](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/418#issuecomment-1992199507), the issue is that in its present version 0.13.2, `xts` makes up some column name for the numeric vector `sp500$SP500`. The behaviour can be avoided by calling `sp500["SP500"]` instead. So, the immediate solution to the problem I posted is:

```
sp500 <- read.csv2("SP500.csv",
                   stringsAsFactors = F,
                   header = T,
                   sep = ",",
                   na.strings = ".")
sp500$DATE <- as.Date(sp500$DATE)
sp500$SP500 <- as.numeric(sp500$SP500)
sp500idx <- xts(sp500["SP500"], order.by = as.Date(sp500$DATE))
```

It goes without saying that the solution @GGrothendieck provided is much more elegant.

Thanks to @GGrothendieck for his insights and to @RuiBaradas for suggesting to contact the maintainer.